# Notepad++ User Defined Language line color based on ending delimiter

Tags: notepad++

I have my language working good except on last rule:

In the following code:

```
Init:
 ErrorMessage, ProgressMessage = ""
 StatusMessage = "No experiment has been performed"
 pi = 3.141592653589793
 alpha = 0.8
```

I would like to color code Init:.

This line type ends in a colon every time, but the preceding text is just a variable.

I would also like to fold it, but if I can't oh well that is not the end of the world.  Mainly I want to color that line.

Answer (score 0):

As of the Notepad++, the answer is simple:
Such a rule is not supported in Notepad++ [UDL2 functionality](http://udl20.weebly.com/introduction.html).

---

If you are open to try another editors where this is possible, let me know and I'll update the answer.